# $PATH/rbenv issue when installing Rails 5.2.4.4 on macOS Big Sur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, rbenv, macos-big-sur

I am trying to install Rails 5.2.4.4 on macOS Big Sur following this tutorial: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11.0-big-sur

However after successfully installing Rails, when attempting to view version using `rails -v`
it comes back with:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

My `$PATH` seems to be the issue, because after running `rbenv rehash` a number of times now it shows as:

```
/Users/abdul/.rbenv/shims:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/shims:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/shims:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/bin:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/bin:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/shims:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/shims:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/shims:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/shims:/Users/abdul/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
```

I tried restarting the shell, didn't help. I also notice now that every time I open terminal the status bar loads through the PATH mentioned above.

Please help as I am a beginner and I desperately need to install rails on my Mac!